# Why am I getting "undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_60_....`" errors in this libcufft_static example?

Tags: c++, cuda, ubuntu-16.04, cufft

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using the CUDA 7.5 SDK, installed via the `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package. I'm trying to compile a simple test program using cuFFT's callback feature; the source code to the example is [available at GitHub](https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples/blob/master/posts/cufft-callbacks/cufft_callbacks.cu).

[Following the instructions for compiling with the callback feature](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-use-cufft-callbacks-custom-data-processing/), I'm compiling the source as relocatable device code and linking against `libcufft_static.a`:

```
nvcc -ccbin g++ -dc -m64 -o cufft_callbacks.o -c cufft_callbacks.cu
nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -o cufft_callbacks cufft_callbacks.o  -lcufft_static -lculibos
```

In the above sequence, the final command fails with a series of errors, all similar to this one:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcufft_static.a(set_callback.o): In function `__sti____cudaRegisterAll_47_tmpxft_00003a6a_00000000_7_set_callback_cpp1_ii_b7e0d86d()':
tmpxft_00003a6a_00000000-4_set_callback.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6fd): undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_47_tmpxft_00003a6a_00000000_7_set_callback_cpp1_ii_b7e0d86d'
```

It complains about many missing symbols, all starting with `__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_`. I don't think I'm doing anything wrong, as the same sequence of commands works properly on a CentOS 7 machine that I have on hand.

Is it possible my SDK is misconfigured somehow? All mentions of similar problems I've seen on SO and elsewhere have been a failure to do the separate compilation steps shown above; I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: I also had no trouble with CUDA 8 RC and CentOS7.  Ubuntu 16.04 is not an officially supported distribution for CUDA 7.5, so I suspect that your CUDA install is indeed broken. It looks like your CUDA install is distributed in unusual places, such as `/usr/lib`

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Thanks for the info. I'll try removing the Ubuntu CUDA toolkit package and install from NVidia's binary installer to see if that helps.

Comment: Your safest bet is to switch to a supported configuration.  CUDA 8.0RC on Ubuntu 16.04 is a supported config.  CUDA 7.5 (regardless of how you install it) is not.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem by upgrading to CUDA 8.0 RC as @RobertCrovella suggested in the comment above. There must be an issue with the 7.5 Ubuntu package.

Comment: It isn't the Ubuntu package. CUDA 7.5 doesn't support gcc version 5. CUDA 8RC does

Comment: @talonmies: I'd call that an issue with the Ubuntu package then; they probably shouldn't even provide one if the distro's packaged version of gcc won't work with it. Alternatively, it should require the installation of an older gcc package (e.g. `gcc-4.9`) that `nvcc` would then be configured to use.

Comment: I don't see `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` listed as one of the recommended packages to use in the [nvidia linux installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation). I don't know who packaged that up.  I think, in general, you're likely to have a better experience if you follow the instructions in the nvidia linux installation guide.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Indeed, I agree that NVidia should be the canonical source for installation instructions. [The `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/nvidia-cuda-toolkit) appears to be maintained by the Ubuntu developers themselves. I (invalidly) assumed that it would be a simple way to install the toolkit when I saw that it was available in the standard repository.